# Django AWS Elastic Beanstalk - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bad-gateway

I have been trawling the internet looking for a solution to this problem and have come up empty handed after trying multiple different things. Im looking to get the vanilla django project deployed on AWS EB. I am new to this so I am sure there is something simple that I am missing. I followed this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html as well as many other YouTube / Stack tutorials and posts hoping to get around this 502 error.

Here is my setup.
[project setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwduT.png)

This is my django.config file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebdjango.wsgi:application
```

Here is my config.yml file:

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: django-env2
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: django-tut
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: Python 3.9
  default_region: us-west-2
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: null
  workspace_type: Application
```

In Settings.py the only change I made was:
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['django-env2.eba-wftrfqr2.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com']`

This is requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.7.2
Django==3.1.3
pytz==2023.3.post1
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.8.0
```

When I run the server locally it works perfectly, giving the generic django page on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (this is before I update ALLOWED_HOSTS of course).

In console its status turns to "Severe" and a warning event is displayed:
"Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Severe. ELB processes are not healthy on all instances. None of the instances are sending data. 50.0 % of the requests to the ELB are failing with HTTP 5xx. Insufficient request rate (2.0 requests/min) to determine application health (4 minutes ago). ELB health is failing or not available for all instances."

I cant really see any more than this. When I hop over the logs tab then there is nothing there. Any help would be appreciated; I feel like I've been hitting my head against a brick wall for days now. Thanks

Comment: you should retrive full logs first.  There are so many possible reasons your deployment fails, all we can know from 502 is that your deployment failed

Comment: I'd recommend setting the log level to DEBUG and redeploying to see what logs are generated during the health checking phase. Provide those here, so we can see what the exact error is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in any config inside *.ebextensions*

Example:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: ebdjango.settings
```